# How can I compile an application that can use the read/write hints in kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile an simple application that uses the read-write hint, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static char const filename[] = "./file.txt";
static char const message[] = "/mnt/pool/my_file\n";

int main(void)
{
    int fp;
    int cnt = 0;
    errno = 0;
    //uint64_t type = RWH_WRITE_LIFE_MEDIUM; <-- [!] not working
    uint64_t type = 3;

    fp = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    if (fp == -1)
        return 1;
    //fcntl(fp, F_SET_RW_HINT, &type); <-- [!] not working
    fcntl(fp, (1024+12), &type);
    cnt = write(fp, message, sizeof(message));

    if(cnt == -1)
        return 1;

    close(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I've found that the `RWH_WRITE_LIFE_MEDIUM` is defined at `include/uapi/linux/fcntl.h`, but I do not know what to do to be able to compile with this options.

Any ideas in how can I compile this without error?

## **EDIT 1:**

Ok, I followed the instructions where I included the `#include <linux/fcntl.h>` and the `#define _GNU_SOURCE` and now I get this error:

```
$ gcc open_file_fcntl.c 
In file included from /usr/include/fcntl.h:35:0,
                 from open_file_fcntl.c:7:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl.h:35:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct flock’
 struct flock
        ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/fcntl.h:1:0,
                 from /usr/include/linux/fcntl.h:5,
                 from open_file_fcntl.c:6:
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:196:8: note: originally defined here
 struct flock {
        ^~~~~
```

I am using `kernel 5.0.0-23-generic`, and `gcc --version 7.4.0`.
Also tested on a QEMU environment using `kernel 4.14.78`, and `gcc --version 4.8.4`.

Comment: Use `#include <linux/fcntl.h>`

Comment: Use `-D_GNU_SOURCE` on the gcc command line, or `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the top of your source file.

Comment: I edited the question adding more information.

Comment: Please, move "Complete Solution" section into your own **answer**: on Stack Overflow we tend to not mix a question and a resolution into a single post.

Comment: If you define `_GNU_SOURCE`, you don't need `#include <linux/fcntl.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to define the `_GNU_SOURCE` macro before `#include <fcntl.h>`. As there may be other interactions, it is better to define it before any `#include` directives:

**open_file_fcntl.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static char const filename[] = "./file.txt";
static char const message[] = "/mnt/pool/my_file\n";

int main(void)
{
    int fp;
    int cnt = 0;
    errno = 0;
    uint64_t type = RWH_WRITE_LIFE_MEDIUM;

    fp = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    if (fp == -1)
        return 1;
    fcntl(fp, F_SET_RW_HINT, &type);
    cnt = write(fp, message, sizeof(message));

    if(cnt == -1)
        return 1;

    close(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, the `#define _GNU_SOURCE` can be removed from the source code (**open_file_fcntl.c** above) and the macro defined on the compiler command line:

```
$ gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE open_file_fcntl.c
```

Answer (score 1):

These are Linux-specific flags, so you need to either pass `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to the compiler or put `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the top of your source file.

Comment: I will accept this as a solution, but I had to also use the `#define HAVE_ARCH_STRUCT_FLOCK` in between the `#include <fcntl.h>` and `#include <linuxfcntl.h>`, so the `struct flock` is not redefined.

Answer (score 0):

After following the other answer, I got a different problem, and for that, I could reach the final solution.

By checking both definitions of the struct flock in the above-mentioned locations, there is a `#define` that can be set at the application layer to avoid the redefinition, which is the `#define HAVE_ARCH_STRUCT_FLOCK`.
It must be added in between the `fcntl.h` includes.
Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define HAVE_ARCH_STRUCT_FLOCK
#include <linux/fcntl.h>

static char const filename[] = "./file.txt";
static char const message[] = "/mnt/pool/my_file\n";

int main(void)
{
    int fp;
    int cnt = 0;
    uint64_t type = RWH_WRITE_LIFE_MEDIUM;

    fp = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    if (fp == -1)
        return 1;

    fcntl(fp, F_SET_RW_HINT, &type);
    cnt = write(fp, message, sizeof(message));

    if(cnt == -1)
        return 1;

    close(fp);
    return 0;
}
```